# Windows Azure: local cache for testing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, caching, azure

I'm new with the Windows Azure platform.
I created a Shared Cache in the cloud (production), but is it possible to simulate a Shared Cache locally? (on my development machine)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no local emulator for Shared Cache. But you can establish a Windows Server AppFabric Cache. It utilizes almost same configuration and code structure. Please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383731(v=azure.10).aspx

But I highly recommended you using the new Cloud Service Cache. It has higher performance, lower cost than Shared Cache. And it has fully development emulator support. For more information please refer to http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/